# What is the best drop-in replacement for numpy.interp if I want the null interpolation (piecewise constant)?

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

`numpy.interp` is very convenient and relatively fast.  In certain contexts I'd like to compare its output against a non-interpolated variant where the sparse values are propagated (in the "denser" output) and the result is piecewise constant between the sparse inputs.  The function I want could also be called a "sparse -> dense" converter that copies the latest sparse value until it finds a later value (a kind of null interpolation as if zero time/distance has ever elapsed from the earlier value).

Unfortunately, it's not easy to tweak the source for `numpy.interp` because it's just a wrapper around a compiled function.  I can write this myself using Python loops, but hope to find a C-speed way to solve the problem.

**Update:** the solution below (`scipy.interpolate.interp1d` with `kind='zero'`) is quite slow and takes more than 10 seconds per call (e.g. input 500k in length that's 50% populated).  It implements `kind='zero'` using a zero-order spline and the call to `spleval` is very slow.  However, the source code for `kind='linear'` (i.e. default interpolation) gives an excellent template for solving the problem using straight numpy (minimal change is to set `slope=0`).  That code shows how to use `numpy.searchsorted` to solve the problem and the runtime is similar to calling `numpy.interp`, so problem is solved by tweaking the `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` implementation of linear interpolation to just skip the interpolation step (slope != 0 blends the adjacent values).

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for the update - I wanted a zero interpolation with `numpy` without entire dependency to `scipy`, and your post update pointed the way to doing it. In a small test I've done, `numpy` 1.5.1: installed 0.8.0 `scipy` with `_fitpack.so` does my test in 308 to 508 μs; while `numpy`-only hacked linear with `slope=0` does the same in 491 to 778 μs - so for me it is slower; but not all that much! Thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` can do all kinds of interpolation: ‘linear’,’nearest’, ‘zero’, ‘slinear’, ‘quadratic, ‘cubic’.

Please check the document: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.10.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d

Comment: Unfortunately it is very slow per update to question.  This is a perfectly valid answer but the underlying Spline implementation is not very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completion: The solution to the question is the following code which I was able to write with the help of the hints given in the updated answer:

```
def interpolate_constant(x, xp, yp):
    indices = np.searchsorted(xp, x, side='right')
    y = np.concatenate(([0], yp))
    return y[indices]
```

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree that kind='zero' is extremely slow; for a large data set of million rows it can take literally 1000 times slower than 'linear' method. For "left-constant" interpolation - using the latest value - the following code works:

```
def approx(x, y, xout, yleft=np.nan, yright=np.nan): 
    xoutIdx     = np.searchsorted(x, xout, side='right')-1
    return (np.where(xout<x[0], yleft, np.where(xout>x[-1], yright, y[xoutIdx])))
```

Coming from R background, this is equivalent to R's approx with f=0. I haven't found a clean way to do this for "right-constant" interpolation because python's np.searchsorted with side='right' pushes one index back if an xout value matches exactly with a value in x...