# Subtracting two interleaved, differently based time-series arrays with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two datasets, `a[ts1]` and `b[ts2]`, where `ts1` and `ts2` are timestamps taken at different times (in different bases?). I wanted to plot `b[ts2]-a[ts1]`, but I think I made a mistake, in that the plotting software understood that I want `b[i]-a[i]` instead, where `i` is the index order of the value.

So I wanted to make a small example of this with `numpy`, and I realized I have no idea whether, and how, `numpy` can perform this operation - but using vectors, and avoiding `for` loops. I have made an example (below), that defines `a[ts1]` and `b[ts2]` as `numpy` structured arrays titled `a_np` and `b_np`:

```
array([(0.0, 0.0), (0.8865606188774109, 0.30000001192092896),
       (1.6939274072647095, 0.6000000238418579),
       (2.3499808311462402, 0.8999999761581421)], ...
      dtype=[('a', '<f4'), ('ts1', '<f4')])
array([(0.3973386585712433, 0.10000000149011612),
       (0.7788366675376892, 0.20000000298023224),
       (1.4347121715545654, 0.4000000059604645), (1.6829419136047363, 0.5)], ...
      dtype=[('b', '<f4'), ('ts2', '<f4')])
```

So my questions here are:

- What is this class of arrays/problems called? Is it just "time-series" arrays? Basically, they describe a 1-D signal, but since timestamps have to be kept, it's a 2D array; and since the "time" column can have any meaning, I guess it can be generalized to interpolation of values of arrays in (value) column, over the "indexing" values in the (time/index) column.
- Can `numpy` do a vectorized operation where the arrays are properly interpolated in "time", before being subtracted?

Looking for info on this, I found [pandas: Python Data Analysis Library](http://pandas.pydata.org/); I guess I should use this instead, given it has a "time-series" functionality - but in this case, I don't need any fancy interpolation of sample values - just a "step" or "hold" one (basically, no interpolation); which is why I was wandering if `numpy` can do that in a vectorized fashion. Otherwise, the example below employs `for` loops.

---

The example will result with an image like this:

[image: array-timeseries]

Arrays `a` and `b` represent values taken at different times, which is indicated by their respective `impulses`; `a` is plotted with `lines` (so, linearly interpolated before plotting), but `b` with `steps` (to indicate the actual values that exist)

The array `d1` represents the "original" difference `b[t]-a[t]` taken when constructing the array - obviously, I do not have access to this data in reality, so I have to work from the sampled values. In that case, the difference `b[ts2]-a[ts1]` is shown as the array/signal `d2`, again as `steps` to emphasize the errors being made in respect to the "original". This `d2` is what I'd like to calculate with `numpy` (but below, it is calculated in the same `for` loop).

The error I made with my plotting software is getting an index-by-index difference of `b` and `a`, or `b[i]-a[i]`; this is shown as array/signal `e` - and as shown, it is *way* off from what it's otherwise supposed to represent. This is only the case if sampling intervals in the two signals are uneven; try `modulowith = 2` in the code, then `e` is actually not that bad - however, my real life case has uneven timestamps, so `b[i]-a[i]` doesn't help me at all.

Here is the code, which also calls `gnuplot` (tested on Python 2.7, `numpy` 1.5 I think):

```python
import subprocess
import math, random
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint
from numpy.lib.recfunctions import append_fields

step = 0.1
modulowith = 3
# must init all arrays separately;
# a=b=[] makes a==b by reference!
ts1 = []; ts2 = [] ; tsd = []
valsa = []; valsb = []; valsd1 = []; valsd2 = []
stra = strb = strd1 = strd2 = "" ; kval1 = kval2 = 0
for ix in range(0, 100, 1):
  ts = ix*step
  val1 = 3.0*math.sin(ts) #+random.random()
  val2 = 2.0*math.sin(2.0*ts)
  if ( ix%modulowith == 0):
    ts1.append(ts) ; valsa.append(val1)
    stra += "%.03f %.06f\n" % (ts, val1)
    kval1 = val1
  else:
    ts2.append(ts) ; valsb.append(val2)
    strb += "%.03f %.06f\n" % (ts, val2)
    kval2 = val2
  tsd.append(ts)
  valb = val2 - val1 ; valsd1.append(valb)
  strd1 += "%.03f %.06f\n" % (ts, valb)
  valc = kval2 - kval1 ; valsd2.append(valc)
  strd2 += "%.03f %.06f\n" % (ts, valc)

a_np = np.array(
  [(_valsa,) for _valsa in valsa],
  dtype=[('a','f4')]
)
b_np = np.array(
  [(_valsb,) for _valsb in valsb],
  dtype=[('b','f4')]
)
a_np = append_fields(a_np, names='ts1', data=ts1, dtypes='f4', usemask=False)
b_np = append_fields(b_np, names='ts2', data=ts2, dtypes='f4', usemask=False)

pprint(a_np[:4])
pprint(b_np[:4])

# e_np = np.subtract(b_np['b'],a_np['a'])
# (via field reference) is same as doing:
# e_np = np.subtract(np.array(valsa, dtype="f4"), np.array(valsb, dtype="f4"))
# but for different sized arrays, must do:
e_np = b_np['b'] - np.resize(a_np, b_np.shape)['a']
pprint(e_np[:4])
e_str = ""
for ts, ie in zip(ts2, e_np):
  e_str += "%.03f %.06f\n" % (ts, ie)


gpscript = """
plot "-" using 1:2 with lines lc rgb "green" t"a", \\
"" using 1:2 with impulses lc rgb "green" t"", \\
"" using 1:2 with steps lc rgb "blue" t"b", \\
"" using 1:2 with impulses lc rgb "blue" t"", \\
"" using 1:2 with lines lc rgb "red" t"d1", \\
"" using 1:2 with steps lc rgb "orange" t"d2", \\
"" using 1:2 with steps lc rgb "brown" t"e"
-
{0}
e
{0}
e
{1}
e
{1}
e
{2}
e
{3}
e
{4}
e
""".format(stra, strb, strd1, strd2, e_str)

proc = subprocess.Popen(
  ['gnuplot','--persist'],
  shell=False,
  stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
)
proc.communicate(gpscript)
```

---

Thanks to the answer by [@runnerup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20449087/277826), here is a slightly verbose (for syntax example purposes) `numpy`-only solution:

```
# create union of both timestamp arrays as tsz
ntz = np.union1d(b_np['ts2'], a_np['ts1'])
# interpolate `a` values over tsz
a_z = np.interp(ntz, a_np['ts1'], a_np['a'])
# interpolate `b` values over tsz
b_z = np.interp(ntz, b_np['ts2'], b_np['b'])
# create structured arrays for resampled `a` and `b`,
# indexed against tsz timestamps
a_npz = np.array( [ (tz,az) for tz,az in zip(ntz,a_z) ],
  dtype=[('tsz', 'f4'), ('a', 'f4')] )
b_npz = np.array( [ (tz,bz) for tz,bz in zip(ntz,b_z) ],
  dtype=[('tsz', 'f4'), ('b', 'f4')] )
# subtract resized array
e_npz = np.subtract(b_npz['b'], a_npz['a'])
e_str = ""

# check:
pprint(e_npz[:4])
# gnuplot string:
for ts, ie in zip(ntz, e_npz):
  e_str += "%.03f %.06f\n" % (ts, ie)
```

This is linearly interpolated, so it will be different from `d2` above, but still nicely fitting.

If there wasn't for those `for` loops creating the arrays, then it is vectorized - and in principle I don't even have to create those arrays - just wanted to see how they will look like as structured ones.. In all, I guess I was hoping for a one-liner that would do this, with structured arrays (that is, handling field names as well).

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240634/what-is-the-best-drop-in-replacement-for-numpy-interp-if-i-want-the-null-interpo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is an attempt to sell you on switching to `pandas`  : )

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# one minute interval
start = dt.datetime.now( )
end = start + dt.timedelta( minutes=1 )

# sin curve at seconds frequancy
idx1 = pd.date_range( start, end, freq='S' )
ts1 = pd.Series( np.sin( np.linspace( 0, 4 * np.pi, len( idx1 ) ) ), index=idx1 )

# cosine curve at milisecond frequency
idx2 = pd.date_range( start, end, freq='L' )
ts2 = pd.Series( np.cos( np.linspace( 0, 4 * np.pi, len( idx2 ) ) ), index=idx2 )
```

now `len( ts1 ) = 61` and `len( ts2 ) = 6001`, with different frequencies

```
fig = plt.figure( figsize=(8, 6) )
ax = fig.add_axes( [.05, .05, .9, .9] )

ts1.plot( ax, color='DarkBlue' )
ts2.plot( ax, color='DarkRed' )

# reindex ts2 like ts1
ts2 = ts2.reindex_like( ts1 )
(ts1 - ts2).plot( ax, color='DarkGreen' )
```

and you get:

[image: time series]

**edit**: for interpolation purposes you may use nonparametric methods in statsmodels, so basically you may interpolate one series at the frequencies of the other one and then subtract the two:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
n = 1000
x = np.linspace( 0, 1, n )
y = np.random.randn( n ).cumsum( )
z = sm.nonparametric.lowess( y, x, return_sorted=False, frac=.05)

ax.plot( x, y, 'Blue', linestyle='--' )
ax.plot( x, z, color='DarkRed' )
```

[image: bm]

Comment: Many thanks, @runnerup - great example! It's going to be a bit of a cognitive load to get into `pandas` for me right now, but it's definitely on the list `:)` I'm still interested if there is a `numpy`-only method for this, however... Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: Many thanks for that @runnerup - your edit gave me an idea of how to do it only in numpy, so I edited the OP (and possibly an idea of how to handle the plotting software). Great tip to know, but in this case I would like to preserve exact timestamp and difference values, so no smoothing (which `lowess` apparently does). In the end, I guess I was hoping for a one-liner for the kind of thing in the OP edit - but three lines isn't that bad `:)` Many thanks again - cheers!

Comment: @sdaau still i am disappointed that you are not switching to pandas :)

Comment: Heh - no worries; as soon as I'm done with my current project, I'm switching `:)` Cheers!