# Normalizing a list of numbers in Python

Tags: python, probability

I need to normalize a list of values to fit in a probability distribution, i.e. between 0.0 and 1.0.

I understand *how* to normalize, but was curious if Python had a function to automate this.

I'd like to go from:

```
raw = [0.07, 0.14, 0.07]
```

to

```
normed = [0.25, 0.50, 0.25]
```

Comment: why wouldnt that be `[0.5, 1.0, 0.5]`?

Comment: @Joran Because OP wants `sum(normed) == 1.0` (ignoring floating point errors).

Comment: See this post if you would like to normalize between a different range. [How to normalize a list of positive and negative decimal number to a specific range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514443/how-to-normalize-a-list-of-positive-and-negative-decimal-number-to-a-specific-ra)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use :

```
norm = [float(i)/sum(raw) for i in raw]
```

to normalize against the sum to ensure that the sum is always 1.0 (or as close to as possible).

use

```
norm = [float(i)/max(raw) for i in raw]
```

to normalize against the maximum

Comment: Nice. It's maybe worth noting that computing the sum in advance, rather than for each element in the comprehension, would be more efficient. So: `s = sum(raw); norm = [float(i)/s for i in raw]`

Comment: Is that the same as `(np.array(x) / np.array(x).sum()) / np.array(x).max()` ?

Comment: @alvas sorry - I can't be sure about numpy - but assuming dividing an array by a single value divides each value in the array; then it looks right.

Comment: Note that in python 3, `float(i)` can be replaced with just `i` to get the same effect.

Answer (score 18):

if your list has negative numbers, this is how you would normalize it

```
a = range(-30,31,5)
norm = [(float(i)-min(a))/(max(a)-min(a)) for i in a]
```

Answer (score 11):

For ones who wanna use [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#normalization), you can use

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

x = [1,2,3,4]
normalize([x]) # array([[0.18257419, 0.36514837, 0.54772256, 0.73029674]])
normalize([x], norm="l1") # array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]])
normalize([x], norm="max") # array([[0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.]])
```

Comment: Or for a completely different kind of normalization: `from sklearn.utils.extmath import softmax` or `from scipy.special import softmax`

Answer (score 7):

How long is the list you're going to normalize?

```
def psum(it):
    "This function makes explicit how many calls to sum() are done."
    print "Another call!"
    return sum(it)

raw = [0.07,0.14,0.07]
print "How many calls to sum()?"
print [ r/psum(raw) for r in raw]

print "\nAnd now?"
s = psum(raw)
print [ r/s for r in raw]

# if one doesn't want auxiliary variables, it can be done inside
# a list comprehension, but in my opinion it's quite Baroque    
print "\nAnd now?"
print [ r/s  for s in [psum(raw)] for r in raw]
```

*Output*

```
# How many calls to sum()?
# Another call!
# Another call!
# Another call!
# [0.25, 0.5, 0.25]
# 
# And now?
# Another call!
# [0.25, 0.5, 0.25]
# 
# And now?
# Another call!
# [0.25, 0.5, 0.25]
```

Answer (score 6):

try:

```
normed = [i/sum(raw) for i in raw]

normed
[0.25, 0.5, 0.25]
```

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any function in the standard library (to my knowledge) that will do it, but there are absolutely modules out there which have such functions.  However, its easy enough that you can just write your own function:

```
def normalize(lst):
    s = sum(lst)
    return map(lambda x: float(x)/s, lst)
```

Sample output:

```
>>> normed = normalize(raw)
>>> normed
[0.25, 0.5, 0.25]
```

Comment: This is one of the two answers that extract `sum()` from the loop... I still prefer mine but I think this is a `+` exactly for the auxiliary variable `s = sum(lst)`.

Comment: `normalize([1,0,-1])` will raise `ZeroDivisionError` :)

Answer (score 4):

If you consider using `numpy`, you can get a faster solution.

```
import random, time
import numpy as np

a = random.sample(range(1, 20000), 10000)
since = time.time(); b = [i/sum(a) for i in a]; print(time.time()-since)
# 0.7956490516662598

since = time.time(); c=np.array(a);d=c/sum(a); print(time.time()-since)
# 0.001413106918334961
```

Comment: Ru sure this equation is right? I am getting vals in d < 0. Not sure if this should happen. Maybe I did something wrong. I am inputting vals from ~ -0.5 to 05.?

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus `random.sample` only works on integer. If float is required, check `np.random.uniform' or something similar instead.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this :**

```
from __future__ import division

raw = [0.07, 0.14, 0.07]  

def norm(input_list):
    norm_list = list()

    if isinstance(input_list, list):
        sum_list = sum(input_list)

        for value in input_list:
            tmp = value  /sum_list
            norm_list.append(tmp) 

    return norm_list

print norm(raw)
```

This will do what you asked.
***But I will suggest to try Min-Max normalization.***

**min-max normalization :**

```
def min_max_norm(dataset):
    if isinstance(dataset, list):
        norm_list = list()
        min_value = min(dataset)
        max_value = max(dataset)

        for value in dataset:
            tmp = (value - min_value) / (max_value - min_value)
            norm_list.append(tmp)

    return norm_list
```

Comment: thanks for the code for min max normalization

Answer (score 2):

*If working with data*, many times `pandas` is the simple key

This particular code will put the `raw` into one column, then normalize by column per row. (But we can put it into a row and do it by row per column, too! Just have to change the `axis` values where 0 is for row and 1 is for column.)

```
import pandas as pd


raw = [0.07, 0.14, 0.07]  

raw_df = pd.DataFrame(raw)
normed_df = raw_df.div(raw_df.sum(axis=0), axis=1)
normed_df
```

where `normed_df` will display like:

```
    0
0   0.25
1   0.50
2   0.25
```

and then can keep playing with the data, too!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a not-terribly-inefficient one liner similar to the top answer (only performs summation once)

```py
norm = (lambda the_sum:[float(i)/the_sum for i in raw])(sum(raw))
```

A similar method can be done for a list with negative numbers

```py
norm = (lambda the_max, the_min: [(float(i)-the_min)/(the_max-the_min) for i in raw])(max(raw),min(raw))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
data = np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(-1, 1)
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(data)
print(scaler.transform(data))
```