# Does Python has a Scale function like D3?

Tags: python, csv, d3.js, scale

I have an entry in a CSV file like this (piece of data):

```
"","x","y","sim1","sim2","sim3","sim4","sim5","sim6","sim7","sim8","sim9","sim10","sim11","sim12"
"1",181180,333740,5.56588745117188,6.29487752914429,7.4835410118103,5.75873327255249,6.62183284759521,5.81478500366211,4.85671949386597,5.90418815612793,6.32611751556396,6.99649047851562,6.52076387405396,5.68944215774536
"2",181140,333700,6.36264753341675,6.5217604637146,6.16843748092651,5.55328798294067,7.00429201126099,6.43625402450562,6.17744159698486,6.72836923599243,6.38574266433716,6.81451606750488,6.68060827255249,6.14339065551758
"3",181180,333700,6.16541910171509,6.44704437255859,7.51744651794434,5.46270132064819,6.8890323638916,6.46842670440674,6.07698059082031,6.2140531539917,6.43774271011353,6.21923875808716,6.43355655670166,5.90692138671875
```

The x and y represents the longitude and latitude for each point in a simulation.
I have to store this in an array. I thought to find the min and max for each x and y and them create a matrix with this dimension and after this do some scale to discover what value should be at the (0,0) (0,1) (0,2) and so on in my matrix.

In D3, there is a [function](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/scales) that do all of this:

```
scaleX = d3.scale.linear().domain([d3.min(simulationDataset, function(d) {return d.x;}), d3.max(simulationDataset, function(d) { return d.x; })]);
scaleY = d3.scale.linear().domain([d3.min(simulationDataset, function(d) {return d.y;}), d3.max(simulationDataset, function(d) { return d.y; })]);
```

There is something similar in Python or I should all of this from zero?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just as a side note -- instead of using both `d3.min` and `d3.max`, you can simply use `d3.extent`.

Comment: Oh and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969240/mapping-a-range-of-values-to-another) should be helpful.

Comment: Hi, @LarsKotthoff. Thanks for the tip in d3. This question that you mentioned is how I'm doing until now. I was wondering if there where a short way, i.e, a short command, to do this, like in d3. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Spectra](https://github.com/jsvine/spectra) library seems to do what you are looking for.  Specifically, the [`spectra.scale`](https://github.com/jsvine/spectra#creating-color-scales).

Answer (score -3):

You probably want to use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) for this sort of thing in Python.

Comment: Yes, @DanielRoseman, I know that the solution probably involves Numpy, but I don't have any idea about how I could achieve what I want.