# How can I use the result from another function?

Tags: python

My code gets a list of numbers (grades) from the user and finds the average based on the numbers the user has given. After finding the average, I want to turn the average into a letter based grade. For example, a 90 average would return "A" and 80 would return "B".

The problem is that I can't use the result (the average) from the  `calculated_average(x)` function and use it at `assign_grade()`.

Any tips?

```
#Gets a list of numbers from user
def get_score():
    score_list = []
    keep_going = 'y'
    while keep_going == 'y':
        score = float(input('Enter a test score: '))
        while score < 0:
            print('Positive numbers only')
            score = float(input('Enter a test score: '))
        score_list.append(score)
        keep_going = input("More scores (y/n) ")
    return score_list

#Calculates the average
def calculated_average(x):
    return sum(x) / len(x)

def assign_grade():





def main():
    score = get_score()
    print(calculated_average(score))

main()
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Why can't you use it?

Comment: Why don't you save the returned result from `calculated_average(score)` in the same way that you saved the score from `get_score()`?

Comment: I can use it to find the average perfectly fine, but I want to turn the average into a letter grade based output instead. I can't seem to find a way to use the output from calculated_average and use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969240/mapping-a-range-of-values-to-another is a more general answer on how to map values.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing something like the code below. `assign_grade` function is very basic here, but you can edit it to your needs:

```
def get_score():
    score_list = []
    keep_going = 'y'
    while keep_going == 'y':
        score = float(input('Enter a test score: '))
        while score < 0:
            print('Positive numbers only')
            score = float(input('Enter a test score: '))
        score_list.append(score)
        keep_going = input("More scores (y/n) ")
    return score_list

#Calculates the average
def calculated_average(x):
    return sum(x) / len(x)

def assign_grade(x):
    if x>80:
        return 'A'
    else:
        return 'B'

def main():
    score = get_score()
    avg = calculated_average(score)
    letter = assign_grade(avg)
    return (letter, avg) 

final = main()
print(final)
```

Output (with input 85):

```
print(final)
('A', 85.0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Is it possible to show both the average and the letter grade? If so, any tips on that?

Comment: you can return a list or a tuple return((avg,letter))

Answer (score 1):

well your code seems to work just you need to finalize the function assign_grade(x)

```
def assign_grade(x):
    if x>=90:
        return("A")
    elif 90>x>=80:
        return("B")
    else:
        return("C")
```