# Map Python timedelta objects onto numerical interval

Tags: python, mapping, interpolation, timedelta, gantt-chart

I have a bunch of `timedelta` objects.

- I want to visualize them by showing them as bars on a common linear time axis (think something like [Gantt charts](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Pert_example_gantt_chart.gif)).
- The end product should be an SVG with a defined total width W (so a time axis with width W, and boxes above it, visualizing the timedeltas).
- The solution should be as precise as possible.

What's the best way to do this?

So far, the best way I've come up with is to

1. *somehow extract an absolute numerical value from all `timedelta` objects (something like Unix Epoch time maybe)*
2. *use the first and last timestamp to define the time range*
3. create a mapping function from the absolute, interpolating the values (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969296/2143578))
4. map the absolute values onto the defined SVG width
5. create the SVG objects using `svgwrite`

After googling for a bit, steps 1 and 2 seem problematic - I'm not even sure `timedelta`s have an absolute numeric value.

Comment: #1 is answered with `timedelta.total_seconds`. The rest of the question is far too broad.

Comment: @chepner That would lose all precision beyond seconds, correct? AFAIK, timedeltas can have up to nanosecond precision.

Comment: Microseconds, but yes, you would lose resolution. However, if the number of microseconds is relevant, you can just compute `1000000*(t.days*86400 + t.seconds) + t.microseconds` yourself to get the total duration in microseconds. (The documentation also mentions dividing `td / timedelta(microseconds=1)` for small intervals.)