# How to interpolate a value in one range into another

Tags: c++, c++11, linear-interpolation, lerp

I have 2 double values which can go from let's say start value `62.243` to end value `79.495`. I have another 2 double values which can go from let's say start value `4.456` to end value `7.687`.

```
double start_1 = 62.243;
double end_1 = 79.495;

double start_2 = 4.456;
double end_2 = 7.687;
```

Now if I a value picked between `start_1` and `end_1`, I want to interpolate the same value to a value between `start_2` and `end_2`.

**Question:**
How do implement the below function in C++ which can do what I described above?

```
double InterpolateAValue(const double start_1, const double end_1, const double start_2, const double end_2, double value_between_start_1_and_end_1) {
     // How to get a value between start_2 and end_2 which matches the position of value_between_start_1_and_end_1 in the range of `start_1` and `end_1`
};
```

I think above function should pass the following unit test.

```
EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(40.0, InterpolateAValue(10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 50.0, 15.0));
```

[std::lerp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lerp) seems to be doing something like what I need but not exactly. I am on C++11. I have taken `double` as the type here. I could have chosen `float`s as well but a wish to see how doubles affect the math is also a part of the question.

Comment: Be careful, mods could mark this as [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5735770/10141528)

Comment: I find it useful to think about it as a two-step process:  first calculate the percentage of the distance of your point p between s1 and e1 (normalized so it’s a double between 0. And 1., with 0.0 meaning p=s1, 1.0 meaning p=s2, 0.5 meaning it’s halfway between them, etc); then calculate the distance between s2 and e2, multiply that by your normalized-percentage, and add the result to s2.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes. That makes a lot of sense. I felt it's such a common need. There must be a question on SO which answers exactly this need.

Comment: Reference implementation in python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969274

Comment: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731863/mapping-a-numeric-range-onto-another/5735770#5735770) has the answer to my question @LeifMessingerLOAF. But does that technique work for doubles as well? I mean doubles precision would not be an issue? I guess it should work for doubles as well but wish to confirm

Comment: I don't understand why `InterpolateAValue(10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 50.0, 5.0)` should be `40.0`. Should the last argument be `15.0`?

Comment: @NathanPierson Ah yes. Sorry. The last argument should be `15.0`. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a number `value_between_start_1_and_end_1`,

```
lambda = (value_between_start_1_and_end_1 - start_1) / (end_1 - start_1)
```

tells you how far you are along the `1`-line. 0 means you're at `start_1`, 1 means you're at `end_1`.

Then use

```
start_2 + lambda * (end_2 - start_2)
```

to get the corresponding position along the `2`-line. I've separated the computation into two stages, but aside from giving up ease of debugging, you could combine in one step.

Personally I'd always use `double`s for this. A `float` could even be slower on modern systems due to unexpected type conversions. Of course you need to check that `start_1` and `end_1` are different.

Comment: Original second formula was incorrect. Sorry ;-)

Comment: Yes. I need to make some checks on `start_1`, `end_1`, `start_2` and `end_2` before running the actual logic

Comment: The point that you made saying I should always use `double`s makes the answer more useful and good to know of the readers of this post :+1

Answer (score 4):

Since C++20 there is [`std::lerp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lerp).

> Computes a+t(b−a), i.e. the linear interpolation between a and b for the parameter t (or extrapolation, when t is outside the range [0,1]).

It does half of what you want. Your `t` is `t = ( value - start_1) / (end_1 - start_1)`. Hence you can do

```
#include <cmath>

double InterpolateAValue(double start_1,double end_1,double start_2, const double end_2, double value) {
    return std::lerp(start_2, end_2, (value - start1) / (end_1 - start_1));
}
```