# How to spread Numpy values on a different interval

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array:

```
a = np.array([20, 10, 5, 15])
```

Given a new interval (for instance B = [10, 40]) I need to spread the values of the original array an the new interval, so the result would be:

```
b = np.array([40., 20, 10., 30])
```

A possible solution would be applying the following formula (in pseudocode) to each value:

```
new_value = min(B) + (current_value - min(a)) * (max(a)-min(a)) / (max(B)-min(B))
```

Any quicker approach ?

Comment: Simple broadcasting? ``b=a*2``

Comment: `np.interp(a, (a.min(),a.max()), (10,40))`, IIUC. Every solution is faster than *pseudo-code*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping a range of values to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969240/mapping-a-range-of-values-to-another)

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, that's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `numpy.interp` like so:

```
np.interp(a, (a.min(),a.max()), (10,40))
```